# How do you store a custom 404 page on the client/browser to show when there's no internet connection?

Tags: caching, browser, http-status-code-404, service-worker

I visited YouTube Music on my browser before realizing I hadn't connected to the internet. Nonetheless, it showed me a custom 404 page [0] instead of showing me the usual thing browsers show when there's no internet.

How can you achieve that?

[0. Image of aforementioned feature.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jljy2.png)

Comment: You need to look up "service workers".

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure what to even search for. So service workers handle that. Beautiful stuff. Have a nice day.